# MsAccess + C# connect to database

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

class AccessConnectPureCode
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string connectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=C:\Users\AAAAA\Documents\Users.mdb";
        OleDbConnection myOleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand myOleDbCommand = myOleDbConnection.CreateCommand();
        myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM User";
        myOleDbConnection.Open();

        // Считываем данные
        OleDbDataReader myOleDbDataReader = myOleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (myOleDbDataReader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Login: {0}, Mail: {1}, Pasword: {2}",
            myOleDbDataReader["Login"],
            myOleDbDataReader["Mail"],
            myOleDbDataReader["Password"]));
        }
        myOleDbDataReader.Close();
        }
}
```

This is my code, I need to connect mdb file to C# Console Application, but here

```
 myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM User";
```

I get an exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Syntax error in FROM clause.

I have all these columns in the table `User` in `Users.mdb`

How can I read fields from that table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [User]";
```

User may be a reserved word in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`User` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) in MS Access. You should use it with square brackets like `[USER]`

```
myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [User]";
```

As a general recomendation, don't use reserved keywords for your identifiers and object names in your database.

> If a reserved word is already in use, you can avoid error messages by
>   surrounding each occurrence of the word with brackets ([ ]). However,
>   the best solution is to change the name to a nonreserved word.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection`, `OleDbCommand` and `OleDbDataReader` like;

```
using(var myOleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using(var myOleDbCommand = myOleDbConnection.CreateCommand())
{
   ...
   ...
   using(var myOleDbDataReader = myOleDbCommand.ExecuteReader())
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`User` is a *reserved* keyword in `TSQL`, see [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).

You need to use *square brackets* to escape it.

```
"SELECT * FROM [User]";
```

Comment: The extra info helps.  All these different SQL engines - each with their own.  I mostly work in MSSQL, so I wasn't sure / couldn't remember..

Comment: This is for **MS Access** SQL - not T-SQL (that's in SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

`user` is a keyword in SQL syntax and you should use `[user]`.

Here is a part of my previous project code :

```
string strconnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=bank.mdb";

    public void InsertMethod(string inputt, string runningtimee, string kindd)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection objconnection = new OleDbConnection(strconnection);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbCommand objcommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Table1" +
                "(db_account_number,db_name,db_family) " +
                "VALUES(@txtaccount,@txtname, @txtfamily)", objconnection);
            objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@db_account_number", runningtimee);
            objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@db_name", kindd);
            objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@db_family", inputt);
            objconnection.Open();
            objcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            objconnection.Close();
        }
        catch (OleDbException a)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
        }
```